# JS -> jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Всем привет. Есть такой input:

```
<input type="text" name="" value="Поиск..." onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Поиск...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Поиск...') this.value='';" />
```

Знатоки поняли, что делает это скрипт. Можно ли утварить такое на jQuery со след. особенностями. Если у инпута класс .mi, то тогда используем этот  скрипт. Берем value, сверяем с изначальным значение и работаем?

У самого не получилось, потому что плохо знаю JS

Comment: Вопрос - можно-ли, ответ - да, можно :)

Comment: Щютник :) А догадаться, что следующий вопрос на полном серьезе будет "Как?"? =)
Так что лучше опережать события, если не указано прямо обратное.

Comment: И докопаетесь же вы..))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

почему бы и нет? (написано на коленке, так что...)

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="mi" value="Поиск..." title="Поиск..." />
<input type="text" name="search2" id="search2" value="Поиск2..." title="Поиск2..." />

$(function() {
    $('input[title].mi').bind({
        focus: function() {
            if ($(this).attr('title') == $(this).attr('value')) {
                $(this).attr('value', '');
            }
        },
        blur: function() {
            if ($(this).attr('value') == '') {
                $(this).attr('value', $(this).attr('title'));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, только уберите пробел тут: input[title].mi

Comment: ну да, убрал :)

Answer (score 2):

да.

```
$('.mi').on('focus',function(){
  if($(this).val()=='Поиск...'){ 
    $(this).val('');
  }
}).on('blur',function(){
  if($(this).val()==''){ 
    $(this).val('Поиск...');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input placeholder="Поиск...">
```

Единственно эта роскошь не работает в IE =(

Ну или можно отуниверсалить так:

```
function eFocus(element){
   if (element.value == element.defaultValue){
       element.focus();
       element.value = '';
   }
}
function eBlur(element){
   if (element.value == ''){
       element.blur();
       element.value = element.defaultValue;
   }
}
<input type="text" value="Поиск..." onfocus="eFocus(this);" onblur="eBlur(this);">
```

Comment: ? вопрос был сделать это на jQuery...